# java.io.IOException: Connexion reset by peer - Titan Gremlin request to get multiple vertices

Tags: gremlin, titan, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I am trying to get multiple vertices from titan using the gremlin request g.V().has('id', within(id1, id2...)).

I have configured an UNIQUE INDEX for the parameter id.

The query is parameterized and  I provide a list of ids (ArrayList) from my java code.

```
g.V().has('idObj', within(i)), params).all().get().stream().map(Result::getVertex).collect(Collectors.toList()
```

As a part of the performance testing, I tried incrementing the number of ids in the list and i noticed that the query executes fine till the list of Ids contain 5000 ids.
Once I submit the query with 10,000 ids, i get the following errors

> 49272 [gremlin-driver-loop-1] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketClientHandler  - Exception caught during WebSocket processing - closing connection
>   java.io.IOException: Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant
>
> ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler  - Could not process the response
>   java.io.IOException: Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant

Below is the complete stack trace.

```
49272 [gremlin-driver-loop-1] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketClientHandler  - Exception caught during WebSocket processing - closing connection
java.io.IOException: Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:311)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
49276 [gremlin-driver-loop-1] ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler  - Could not process the response
java.io.IOException: Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:311)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
        at com.gfi.sherloqq.java.titan.Vertices.getBySherloqqIds(Vertices.java:188)
        at Main.main(Main.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultQueue.drainTo(ResultQueue.java:102)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet.lambda$all$13(ResultSet.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:311)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        ... 1 more
```

Did any one face this issue? Could you please tell me if there is a limitation on the max number of IDs we can send in one request?

> Our environment: CDH 5.7.1, Titan 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT, Solr 4.10.3, HBase 1.2.0, titan-tp3-driver to create remote connection to gremlin server and for querying

Comment: That's the driver stack trace as best i can tell. Is there a server stacktrace? I think that one would provide better information as to why it went bad in the first place?

Comment: I had searched in the server logs in the file "gremlin-server.log" but unfortunately there is nothing . I did a `tail -f` of this file and relaunched the my tests several times. The jar fails with the same error despite nothing being written in the gremlin-server.log file

Comment: Are you saying the server log file is empty? or that you when you say "nothing being written" you mean, there appears to be nothing related to this client side error being written?

Comment: When i launch my job, it doesn't write anything in the gremlin log file. However the gremlin logfile is not empty it contains some other messages/ warnings etc that happened before i executed my job.